# Prove that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>x$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I solved this and I think it is correct but being new to Real Analysis without much proofs experience there is always this hesitancy I have during/after solving so I am posting this in 'solution-verification'

> Prove that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$  $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $n>x$

My attempt:

Assume that this statement is incorrect, this means that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$  $\nexists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>x$

So we now have that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $x\geq n$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Since we are talking about all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}$ we can say that $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$ $x\geq n$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

This implies that $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above which is wrong, thus our initial statement must be correct.

Any feedback or help would be appreciated. My goal from this is to either verify it is correct or get to know where I went wrong so I am not really interested in someone giving me another solution.

Comment: How do you know that the naturals aren't bounded above? There are examples of ordered sets containing the naturals where the naturals are bounded.

Comment: I said that the set of natural numbers isn't bounded above, not that a set containing natural numbers isn't bounded above. It is a pretty known property, check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property

Comment: What I was aiming at is that the result you're supposed to prove is one of the equivalent ways to formulate the Archimedean property. You're essentially proving that one formulation of the Archimedean property implies another (and the implication is a trivial one: both formulations are really just different ways to say that no real is larger than all naturals). Are you sure that you're not supposed to prove that the reals are Archimedean in the first place? In which case you shouldn't use the Archimedean property.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos well this one a small task given in class, we learned the Archimedean property before it so I think my way is fine.

Comment: Yeah, in that case it's probably fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given statement is

> $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}  \,\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n >x$

If the above statement is incorrect then it should be

> $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}  \,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \le x$

and not

> So we now have that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $x\geq n$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

**Edit:**
Your can use the same argument. Remember the definition of bounded subsets of real numbers. A subset $A$ of real numbers is said to be bounded if $\exists M \in \mathbb{R} \forall a \in A$ we have $a \le M$.

Here you can take $A= \mathbb{N}, M = x$.

Comment: thank you! but given your statement, wouldn't the rest of my proof still apply?

Comment: @Sergio Yes it is valid, please look at the edit

Comment: thank you for the help